# Prevent copy/paste and right-click meant for textbox (email address)

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, copy-paste, right-click

I would like to prevent a user from either:

1. Copy and pasting from the first textbox to the second
2. Right-click and use the context menu to copy and paste from the first textbox to the second.

This is not working.

```html
<html>
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Confirm email page</title>
    <script  type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function DisableRightClick(event) {
        //For mouse right click 
        if (event.button == 2) {

        }
    }
    function DisableCtrlKey(e) {
        var code = (document.all) ? event.keyCode : e.which;
        // look for CTRL key press
        if (parseInt(code) == 17) {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
    </script>

  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 1em">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <h1>Confirm Email</h1>
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter Email Address: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" oncopy="return false" onMouseDown="DisableRightClick(event)" ></asp:TextBox><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Confirm Email Address: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" onKeyDown="return DisableCtrlKey(event)"></asp:TextBox><br />
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

**GOT IT WORKING!!!!**

```
<div>
<h1>Copy Paste Preventer!!!</h1>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Username: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter Email Address: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"  oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncontextmenu="forms[0].elements[0].value++; return false"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Confirm Email Address: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncontextmenu="forms[0].elements[0].value++; return false"> </asp:TextBox><br />
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "ASP.Net c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div>
<h1>Copy Paste Preventer!!!</h1>
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Enter Username: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Enter Email Address: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="email" runat="server"  oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncontextmenu="forms[0].elements[0].value++; return false"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Confirm Email Address: "></asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" oncopy="return false" onpaste="return false" oncut="return false" oncontextmenu="forms[0].elements[0].value++; return false"> </asp:TextBox><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

When using jQuery this is fairly simple and it is fully compatible with ASP.NET:

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js'>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $('input[id$=TextBox2]').bind('cut copy paste', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert('You cannot ' + e.type + ' text!');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is an article that explains how this works together with ASP.NET:
http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=398

As Scott pointed out: In production, you should put the jQuery reference on the bottom of your html however(still inside the body tag).

**UPDATE**
Since you asked to prevent the context menu entirely you can do something like this:

Add this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('TextBox2').oncontextmenu = function (){
        return false;
    };
</script>
```

The menu item is not shown when `false` is returned. Here is an overview of browsersupport for this:
http://help.dottoro.com/ljhwjsss.php

Comment: I would select the elements by class $(".noCopy").bind(...

Then this restriction can be placed on any element with that CSS class

Comment: +1 for this answer. Just to be thorough, any Javascript solution can be bypassed by disabling JS in the browser. But that is beyond the average user.

Comment: Thank you.  The problem is that I don't want an alert.  I would prefer that the windows context menu not show up when you right-click and that the ctrl fuctions of copy and paste are not permitted.

Comment: I've seen this in lots of production sites where they want the user to enter and confirm their email address.

Comment: +1 Good answer. However, I disagree with your production / jQuery reference in your html head comment.  The recommended best practice is to have ALL javascript at the bottom of the page right before the ending `</body>` tag for faster loading, preferably in one single script.js reference and never inline.  Check out http://html5boilerplate.com/ for all recommended best practices.

Comment: @Scott I actually mean, don't inline it ;)

Comment: @Susan I added another approach preventing the context from being shown

Comment: @Scott Incorporated your feedback into the answer, thx again for the tip.

Comment: I'm getting an error saying that oncontextmenu is NOT an attribute of <body>

Comment: @Susan Since it is an js event I guess it might not be valid xhtml, I simplified the solution even further, check the updated code.